# What is the best Terraform solution to apply 2 main.tf files without replicating the common modules twice?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

This is my folder format.

[image: Folder format]

In services directory directory_A and directory_B can independently be applied.
My requirement is to create a main.tf in services and on applying it both directory_A and directory_B should be applied. Common modules should not get created twice rather it should apply directory_A and grab common_modules values for directory_B.
I am new to terraform. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear. Please provide more details, maybe some actual TF code of your demonstrating what you want to do.

Comment: From what I understand, you would need one *root* module which would invoke modules from directories A and B. Also, make sure you output the values you need from the module in directory B so they can be consumed by A.